# Kuberenetes Ingress - Whitelist particular APIs

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, whitelist

We have a host of microservices all being served via a single api-gateway service, in Kubernetes, with an ingress to forward to the same that looks like below ->

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: beta-https
  namespace: beta
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - beta.xyz.com
      secretName: beta-secret
  rules:
  - host: beta.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: api-svc
          servicePort: 8443
```

Now we have a new requirement, wherein a subset of the apis - /api/secure , must be IP restricted. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I am assuming I can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range`, in a new config to foroward traffic to /api/secure, but how do I ensure the above config does not server /api/secure?

Answer (score 0):

so for someone looking into doing something similar, I was able to get this working by using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` to add a snippet and block the traffic

```
      location ~ "^/api/secure/(.*)" {
        deny all;
        return 403;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are trying to create two separate paths where `/api/secure` will be accesible only for specific ip addresses.

I have replicated your problem, made some tests and found a solution.

When creating two ingress objects like yours, which differ on `path` field e.g.
one has `path: /api/(.*)` and second has `path: /api/secure`

nginx will generate the following configuration (output is shortened):

server {
      server_name beta.xyz.com ;

```
  listen 80  ;
  listen 443  ssl http2 ;

      ...

  location ~* "^/api/secure" {
      ...
  }

  location ~* "^/api/(.*)" {
      ...
  }
```

and in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) you can read:

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations
>   defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the `location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered`. Then regular expressions
>   are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of
>   regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used.

meaning: NGINX always fulfills requests using the most specific match

Based on this information, creating two separate ingresses, just like you mentioned,
should solve your problem, because `/api/secure` will always be more specific path than `/api/(.*)`.

Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i have a multi subdomain host plateform and i am trying configs such as

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  location ~* "^/api/architect/(.*)" {
      allow  all;
  }

  location ~* "^/(.*)" {
      deny  all;
      allow 149.74.110.92;
      allow 85.138.230.206;
  }
```

but doesn't seems working so far. I want to block the main url and only access a certain endpoint...